# SELECT DISTINCT query / subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT user_set, read, last_updated, user_id, pk_id
FROM interaction_log
WHERE user_id = 2002
ORDER BY read, last_updated, user_set
```

The database in use is PostgreSQL (9.1) and the requirement is something like this:

- The ordering of the columns may not change (arrange by read status, then by the last update and then by user_set)
- The 'read' column is an integer which can take a value of only '1' or '0'. last_updated is a positive integer and user_set is a string.
- The user_set column has to be unique. e.g.: if there are 3 entries for a user_set named 'devs' like below:

  1. user_set = "devs" , read = 1, last_updated = 10, user_id = 2002, pk_id = 1
  2. user_set = "devs" , read = 0, last_updated = 30, user_id = 2002, pk_id = 3
  3. user_set = "devs" , read = 0, last_updated = 20, user_id = 2002, pk_id = 2

Then the second entry (with pk_id = 3) should come at the top and none others should show up because it was 'read = 0' and then it's last_updated value was 30 (higher than 20).

SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_set) wants me to have user_set as the first sort order which would change the ordering and hence I cannot do it.

If I do something like this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_set) user_set, read, last_updated, thread_id, user_id, id
 FROM message_interaction_log 
    WHERE (user_set, read, last_updated, thread_id, user_id, id) IN
        (SELECT user_set, read, last_updated, thread_id, user_id, id 
            FROM message_interaction_log
            WHERE user_id = 14
            ORDER BY read DESC, last_updated, user_set)
```

Then the 'order by' effect on 'read' is invisible and doing 'read ASC' and 'read DESC' remains the same.

I have tried doing everything I could and I failed every single time. Any help would me much appreciated.

Comment: maybe look up Select MAX(column): http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-agg.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user_set, read, last_updated, user_id, pk_id
FROM message_interaction_log 
WHERE (user_set, last_updated) IN (
  SELECT user_set, max(last_updated)
  FROM message_interaction_log
  WHERE user_id = 2002
  GROUP BY user_set
)
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9a044/6.

Comment: Added the ORDER BY clause to your solution @Guntram :) And many thanks. I have been struggling with this since last 2 days. I need to do more SQLing I think. :P